# Prefix -g is not recognized as an internal and external command in npm

Tags: ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4IIY.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILSu9.png)I was trying to implement an ionic framework project.
First I installed nodejs in my system.
Then I typed `npm -v` in cmd.
I always get an error that `Prefix -g is not recognized as an internal and external command`, even if i have configured the path in Environment Variable in system properties.

With this issue I successfully installed gulp, bower, cordova.
But while I install ionic using `npm install -g cordova ionic`, I always get the error message.

Please help me out of this.

Thanks
Abinas

Comment: which OS? is node correctly installed. try run 'node -v'

Answer (score 0):

After the Node.js installation you must to install Npm and only after  you can ask for npm  version. Usually on Windows it is so.

Comment: using npm i installed gulp, bower and cordova. But can't install ionic